Prove that the integer sequence $a_1,a_2,...,a_p$ is an AP iff there exists a partion of the set of natural numbers into $p$ disjoint sets
'Let $p$ be an odd prime number and consider the following sequence
of integers: $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_{p−1}, a_p$. Prove that this sequence is an arithmetic progression
if and only if there exists a partition of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ into $p$ disjoint
sets $A_1, A_2 ,\cdots, A_{p−1}, A_p$ such that the sets $\{a_i + n | n\in A_i\}$ (for $i = 1, 2, · · · , p$) are
identical.'
Here's my approach to the problem. We will prove both directions.
Suppose the given sequence of integers is an AP $\implies a_i=a_1+(i-1)d$ for $i\in \{1,2,\cdots,p\}$  where $d$ is the common difference cooprime to $p$.Thus for any distinct $i,j \in\{1,2,\cdots,p\}$we have the following congruences \begin{cases}a_i\equiv a_1+(i-1)d\pmod  p\\a_j\equiv a_1+(j-1)d\pmod p\end{cases}
substracting both congruences we obtain $$a_i-a_j\equiv (i-j)d\pmod p$$
Since $i,j<p$  thus $$a_i\equiv a_j+k\pmod p$$ for $k\equiv (i-j)d\ (mod\ p)\in \{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$.
Hence set $A_i=A_j+\{n|n\equiv k\pmod p\}$.
Now the other way , let's suppose there exists a partition of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ into $p$ disjoint sets $A_1, A_2 ,\cdots, A_{p−1}, A_p$ such that the sets $\{a_i + n | n\in A_i\}$ (for $i = 1, 2, · · · , p$) then for distinct $i,j\in\{1,2,\cdots,p\}$ we have $$\{a_i + n | n\in A_i\}=\{a_j + n | n\in A_j\}$$ where $A_i=\{n|n\equiv i\pmod p\}$ $$\implies a_i+px+i=a_j+py+j$$ for some integers $x,y$ $$\implies a_i\equiv a_j+j-i\pmod p$$. Letting $j=i-1$
we obtain $a_i-a_{i-1}\equiv -1\pmod p$ $\implies a_i-a_{i-1}= -1 +pz=constant$ for some integer $z$. $\square$
After this i pounder if this will still hold for any positive integer $n$

Shouldn't it be $$a_i-a_j\equiv(i-j)d\pmod p?$$

I think this is a "solution-verification" and added the tag. If yes, please "identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.". If no, please remove the tag.

@Thomas Andrews
Yes it should sorry man

@Calvin Lin
Sorry but i dont understand clearly what you mean

My doubt is to know if this solution can still hold for any positive integer n instead of p

@BrayantTagne I added the "solution-verification" tag to your post. (EG You can see the edit that I made). $\quad$ Per the description in the post, it is MSE policy that "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. "

Whereas, if your goal is just "After this i pounder if this will still hold for any positive integer " which is buried at the very end, then you should make this much more obvious. EG It should align with your title.
